# C++ Threading using 2 Containers

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following problem. I use a vector that gets filled up with values from a temperature sensor. This function runs in one thread. Then I have another thread responsible for publishing all the values into a data base which runs once every second. Now the publishing thread will lock the vector using a mutex, so the function that fills it with values will get blocked. However, while the thread that publishes the values is using the vector I want to use another vector to save the temperature values so that I don't lose any values while the data is getting published. How do I get around this problem? I thought about using a pointer that points to the containers and then switching it to the other container once it gets locked to keep saving values, but I dont quite know how.

I tried to add a minimal reproducable example, I hope it kind of explains my situation.

```
void publish(std::vector<temperature> &inputVector)
{
    //this function would publish the values into a database
    //via mqtt and also runs in a thread.
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<temperature> testVector;
    std::vector<temperature> testVector2;

    while(1)
    {
        //I am repeatedly saving values into the vector. 
        //I want to do this in a thread but if the vector locked by a mutex
        //i want to switch over to the other vector
        testVector.push_back(testSensor.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your code ([mcve]).

Comment: If you use Visual C++ you can use the classes in the Concurrency Runtime like [Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/asynchronous-agents-library?view=vs-2019) to make the problem a *lot* easier. The publisher and subscriber become agents and the library takes care of synchronization between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `std::mutex`, you can use [`mutex::try_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock) on the producer side. Something like this:

```
while(1)
{
    if (myMutex.try_lock()) {
         // locking succeeded - move all queued values and push the new value
         std::move(testVector2.begin(), testVector2.end(), std::back_inserter(testVector));
         testVector2.clear();
         testVector.push_back(testSensor.getValue());
         myMutex.unlock();
    } else {
         // locking failed - queue the value
         testVector2.push_back(testSensor.getValue());
    }
}
```

Of course `publish()` needs to lock the mutex, too.

```
void publish(std::vector<temperature> &inputVector)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(myMutex);
    //this function would publish the values into a database
    //via mqtt and also runs in a thread.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems like the perfect opportunity for an additional (shared) buffer or queue, that's protected by the lock.

`main` would be essentially as it is now, pushing your new values into the shared buffer.

The other thread would, when it can, lock that buffer and take the new values from it. This should be very fast.

Then, it does not need to lock the shared buffer while doing its database things (which take longer), as it's only working on its own vector during that procedure.

Here's some pseudo-code:

```
std::mutex pendingTempsMutex;
std::vector<temperature> pendingTemps;

void thread2()
{
   std::vector<temperature> temps;
   while (1)
   {
      // Get new temps if we have any
      {
         std::scoped_lock l(pendingTempsMutex);
         temps.swap(pendingTemps);
      }

      if (!temps.empty())
         publish(temps);
   }
}

void thread1()
{
    while (1)
    {
        std::scoped_lock l(pendingTempsMutex);
        pendingTemps.push_back(testSensor.getValue());

        /*
        Or, if getValue() blocks:

        temperature newValue = testSensor.getValue();

        std::scoped_lock l(pendingTempsMutex);
        pendingTemps.push_back(newValue);
        */
    }
}
```

Usually you'd use a `std::queue` for `pendingTemps` though. I don't think it really matters in this example, because you're always consuming *everything* in thread 2, but it's more conventional and can be more efficient in some scenarios. It can't lose you much as it's backed by a `std::deque`. But you can measure/test to see what's best for you.

This solution is pretty much what you already proposed/explored in the question, except that the producer shouldn't be in charge of managing the second vector.

You can improve it by having `thread2` wait to be "informed" that there are new values, with a condition variable, otherwise you're going to be doing a lot of busy-waiting. I leave that as an exercise to the reader ;) There should be an example and discussion in your multi-threaded programming book.